# AuthorizationCodeProvider could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently doing a small poc on Microsoft Graph API by following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) but facing an issue where `AuthorizationCodeProvider` could not be found. I've installed all the necessary packages and all. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your codes, I found you don't add `Microsoft.Graph.Auth;` namespace in your codes.

I suggest you could try to add `using Microsoft.Identity.Client; using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;` and test again.